# touchesBegan Vs UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer, touchesbegan

So I'm making a spritekit game using swift. And I was wondering which is best to use gesture wise?

Currently I have a `override func touchesBegan` handling all taps and a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` handling long taps/holds.

So you know, a tap presses buttons and jumps the hero. The long hold makes the hero duck.

For some reason my longPress function isn't always called (sometimes you can press and hold 10 times and then it stops being called (isn't recognised), other times it's 5, it varies), and this led to a whole day yesterday trying new things and investigating, which brought me to this question.

Is it better to use `touchesBegan` or move all my touch calls to a new function handled by a `UITapGestureRecognizer`?

I did move everything from `touchesBegan` to `UITapGestureRecognizer` but it seems very sluggish. But I may have been implementing it wrong?

This is how the `recognisers` are set up:

```
func setupRecognizers() {
    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTap:"))
    view!.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)

    let longTapRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleLongPress:"))
    longTapRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.2
    view!.addGestureRecognizer(longTapRecognizer)

}
```

These are the functions that handle the gestures:

```
func handleTap(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    //currently all handled in touchesBegan
}

func handleLongPress(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    print("1 --------> longPress Called.... ", recognizer.state.rawValue, gameState)
    if gameState == .Play {
       //do stuff
       //duck Hero
    } else {
       //switch gameState
    }
}
```

This is the function that handles the touches/taps:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */

for touch in touches {
     let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

     //do stuff

     switch gameState {
        case .MainMenu:
        break
        ... //more states
        }
   }
   super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
}
```

If I move everything from `touchesBegans` to a `tapRecogniser` (the empty function above), I have to implement this too, to convert the touch location coordinates:

```
func handleTap(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let location = convertPointFromView(CGPoint(x: recognizer.locationInView(nil).x, y: recognizer.locationInView(nil).y))
    print("Converted Coords: ", location)

    //then do all touchesBegan stuff
 }
```

I've tried both, but the latter seems realllllly slow and sluggish. Maybe I'm forgetting to implement something that is recommended?

Seems my longPress gesture doesn't always get called, could there be some conflict between these?

Comment: i wouldnt use anything UIKit related in a spritekit game.  if you want to test how long a touch is just time it using your update method.  try to use as much of spritekit's tools as possible in your game.  Anything UIKit related (game menu, or controls) I would place inside of UIViewController.

Comment: Everything, including the menu is created in the gameScene and differentiated by gameStates (inGame, Menu, gameOver) etc. So you recommend a timer in the `touchesBegan`, and `if timer > longPressValue duck, else jump?` Or does SpriteKit has different tapGestures?

Comment: it doesnt have tapgestures.. you just need to capture the time youre holding your finger down, and reset the timer when you let go.  that kinda thing.

Comment: I'll give it ago, it might solve why the longPress isn't always called and keeps everything inside touchesBegan... might work better.

Comment: sure let me know if you need me to write some code

Comment: @hamobi if you'd like to write an example in an answer below, that would be really cool. I'm sure your implement would be more efficient than what mine would :) Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so if you hold on the red square for two seconds you'll get a message, when you let go the message disappears.  you might have to add some booleans in there to make sure your character isnt repeating some action every frame after the 2 second button hold.  this should be enough to get you started hopefully

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    // time values
    var delta = NSTimeInterval(0)
    var last_update_time = NSTimeInterval(0)

    var longTouchTimer = NSTimeInterval(0)
    var touched = false
    var testLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "you have touched for awhile now bro")

    let touchSprite = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(100, 100))

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        touchSprite.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2)
        addChild(touchSprite)

        testLabel.hidden = true
        testLabel.position = touchSprite.position
        testLabel.position.y += 100
        testLabel.fontSize = 20
        addChild(testLabel)
    }


    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            if touchSprite.containsPoint(location) {
                touched = true
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            if !touchSprite.containsPoint(location) {
                touched = false
                longTouchTimer = 0
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        touched = false
        longTouchTimer = 0
    }

    override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
        if last_update_time == 0.0 {
            delta = 0
        } else {
            delta = currentTime - last_update_time
        }

        last_update_time = currentTime

        if touched {
            longTouchTimer += delta
        }

        if longTouchTimer >= 2 {
            testLabel.hidden = false
        } else {
            testLabel.hidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh awesome. Thank you. I'll give it a shot now. Thanks for posting.

Comment: @hamobi great writeup. Just using the the touches methods to start and stop timers (NSTimeIntervals not NSTimer which shouldn't be used in SpriteKit) while using the updates currentTime is perfect. Note that because you are using the currentTime instead of a system time it works great when the game is paused for any reason.

Comment: I'm just getting a blank screen.. maybe I'm doing something dumb :S

Comment: It might be the way your particular project is set up.. Ultimately the part that matters is using update to increment your time variable.  Just try adding that piece to your project

Comment: Got it working, think my project was weird. Deleted it and started again and works fine... Is there a way to have the `longTouchTimer` work inside the `touchesBegan`? Because like you say, if I just jump() or duck() in the update, it will be called every frame

Comment: You just need to add a Boolean to jump or duck to check if you're already jumping or ducking.

Comment: @hamobi just to let you know, it seems I finally have everything working and it's really smooth, literally better than the long gesture touches. So thank you so much! :D